# Block badbot with fail2ban via user agents in access.log

Tags: fail2ban

How can I create a filter to block these with fail2ban?

```
    476 Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; BLEXBot/1.0; +http://webmeup-crawler.com/)
    892 ltx71 - (http://ltx71.com/)
    5367 Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; DotBot/1.1; http://www.opensiteexplorer.org/dotbot, help@moz.com)
   6449 Barkrowler/0.9 (+http://www.exensa.com/crawl)
```

This list come out from this:

```
sudo cat /var/log/apache2/access.log | awk -F\" '{print $6}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

I've tried apache-badbot.conf, but it does not seem to work ...

Comment: Those are user agents, not referrers. In my experience DotBot and BLEXBot obey robots.txt, if a `Disallow` directive exits for them. ltx71 ignores robots.txt, and I had to block all of their IP addresses (at the time: 54.174.24.200, 54.175.147.90, 54.175.196.96) via (in my case) iptables rules.

Comment: I looked at your previous questions, and realize that you have been having issues for months. It is not clear to me why you are having so many continuing issues with the typical ways of dealing with these type bots. By the way, my iptables rules for ltx71.com are because those 3 IP addresses did not identify themselves as `ltx71` via user agent string. I also have rewrite rules that allow ltx71 to get my robots.txt file, but otherwise tell them they are banned because they don't obey the robots.txt file.

Comment: "Those are user agents" - You're right... sorry I got confused after all this googling.

These are the ones that are in my robots.txt, but they ignore the directive.

At the end after the old thread I created a dynamic robots.txt that updates simultaneously in all my sites, and contains about fifty working rules.

Until some time ago, I added with a script all the IPs of unwanted bots to UFW,  but at one point I arrived at thousands of IP, and I had to look for another way. Of ltx71 I have two new ones only today (35.192.84.7, 104.155.179.226).

Comment: After a lot of trouble, I gave up on 35.zzz.yyy.xxx and now block 35.0.0.0/8. I don't care about blocking someone innocent as collateral damage.

Comment: After a while I also started using CIDR, but they were hundreds, which means hundreds of thousands of innocent IPs blocked.

The problem is not the blocked IP, but if the server is small takes longer to control iptables than to show the page, with each connection.

Comment: I did some other research using Fail2ban and User Agents this time, I have not found much, almost nothing... it means that it is an extremely stupid and simple thing to do that does not need to talk about it, or that is something that you can not do?

Comment: `Fail2ban` is for blocking authentication.. so, unless these robots try to authenticate, I don't think you can block them with `Fail2ban`

Comment: @RobertRiedl You can also use fail2ban to block IPs that are obviously looking for exploit paths such as admin paths and script extensions from unrelated frameworks.

Comment: @alebal I noticed you have a decent number of questions and none of them have an answer marked as accepted. If none of them have been answered to your satisfaction, that's completely alright. If some have been answered satisfyingly, you should mark the best answer as "accepted". See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) for more information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct way to deal with annoying bots is to block them in "robots.txt". But your comments indicate they're ignoring that directive. Blocking by user-agent will ultimately be a cat and mouse game, but if you want to do it you want the following.

So, you need to enable the *apache-badbots* jail that reads the Apache access log if you haven't already. Create the file `/etc/fail2ban/jail.d/apache-badbots.local` with the contents:

```ini
[apache-badbots]
enabled = true
```

The main portion of the *apache-badbots* jail is defined in `/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf` so all you have to do is enable it.

Next, modify the *apache-badbots* filter to include your bots. Edit `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/apache-badbots.conf`. In it there is a particular line for custom bots:

```ini
badbotscustom = EmailCollector|WebEMailExtrac|TrackBack/1\.02|sogou music spider
```

The bots are specified using a regular expression. Either replace those or tack yours on the end separated with `|`s.

```ini
badbotscustom = EmailCollector|WebEMailExtrac|TrackBack/1\.02|sogou music spider|BLEXBot|ltx71|DotBot|Barkrowler
# OR
badbotscustom = BLEXBot|ltx71|DotBot|Barkrowler
```

Next, you'll want to modify the `failregex` line so that the regular expression matches any part of the user agent, not just the whole thing. Change the line:

```ini
failregex = ^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST).*HTTP.*"(?:%(badbots)s|%(badbotscustom)s)"$
```

to (note the two additional `.*`):

```ini
failregex = ^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST).*HTTP.*".*(?:%(badbots)s|%(badbotscustom)s).*"$
```

Finally, reload the fail2ban configurations.

```sh
sudo fail2ban-client reload
```

---

This information may be helpful for reference.

Looking at `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/apache-badbots.conf` on an update to date Ubuntu 16.04 server I have, it looks outdated. In particular there's this comment:

```
# DEV Notes:
# List of bad bots fetched from http://www.user-agents.org
# Generated on Thu Nov  7 14:23:35 PST 2013 by files/gen_badbots.
```

I generated a new one from the [fail2ban](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban) git repository, but it still didn't include those bots (maybe the source is outdated or incomplete). If you're curious, you can generate a new one with following.

```sh
git clone https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban
cd fail2ban/
./files/gen_badbots
```

The new file will be available at `config/filter.d/apache-badbots.conf` ([here](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/master/config/filter.d/apache-badbots.conf) on Github). If you want to use it replace `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/apache-badbots.conf` with it.

For reference, this is the definition of *apache-badbots* from `/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf`.

```ini
[apache-badbots]
# Ban hosts which agent identifies spammer robots crawling the web
# for email addresses. The mail outputs are buffered.
port     = http,https
logpath  = %(apache_access_log)s
bantime  = 172800
maxretry = 1
```

The `%(apache_access_log)s` variable comes from `/etc/fail2ban/paths-debian.conf` and is defined as `/var/log/apache2/*access.log`.

For reference, here is the `apache-badbots.conf` that I generated (without modifications).

```ini
# Fail2Ban configuration file
#
# Regexp to catch known spambots and software alike. Please verify
# that it is your intent to block IPs which were driven by
# above mentioned bots.


[Definition]

badbotscustom = EmailCollector|WebEMailExtrac|TrackBack/1\.02|sogou music spider
badbots = Atomic_Email_Hunter/4\.0|atSpider/1\.0|autoemailspider|bwh3_user_agent|China Local Browse 2\.6|ContactBot/0\.2|ContentSmartz|DataCha0s/2\.0|DBrowse 1\.4b|DBrowse 1\.4d|Demo Bot DOT 16b|Demo Bot Z 16b|DSurf15a 01|DSurf15a 71|DSurf15a 81|DSurf15a VA|EBrowse 1\.4b|Educate Search VxB|EmailSiphon|EmailSpider|EmailWolf 1\.00|ESurf15a 15|ExtractorPro|Franklin Locator 1\.8|FSurf15a 01|Full Web Bot 0416B|Full Web Bot 0516B|Full Web Bot 2816B|8484 Boston Project v 1\.0|Atomic_Email_Hunter/4\.0|atSpider/1\.0|autoemailspider|bwh3_user_agent|China Local Browse 2\.6|ContactBot/0\.2|ContentSmartz|DataCha0s/2\.0|DBrowse 1\.4b|DBrowse 1\.4d|Demo Bot DOT 16b|Demo Bot Z 16b|DSurf15a 01|DSurf15a 71|DSurf15a 81|DSurf15a VA|EBrowse 1\.4b|Educate Search VxB|EmailSiphon|EmailSpider|EmailWolf 1\.00|ESurf15a 15|ExtractorPro|Franklin Locator 1\.8|FSurf15a 01|Full Web Bot 0416B|Full Web Bot 0516B|Full Web Bot 2816B|8484 Boston Project v 1\.0|Atomic_Email_Hunter/4\.0|atSpider/1\.0|autoemailspider|bwh3_user_agent|China Local Browse 2\.6|ContactBot/0\.2|ContentSmartz|DataCha0s/2\.0|DBrowse 1\.4b|DBrowse 1\.4d|Demo Bot DOT 16b|Demo Bot Z 16b|DSurf15a 01|DSurf15a 71|DSurf15a 81|DSurf15a VA|EBrowse 1\.4b|Educate Search VxB|EmailSiphon|EmailSpider|EmailWolf 1\.00|ESurf15a 15|ExtractorPro|Franklin Locator 1\.8|FSurf15a 01|Full Web Bot 0416B|Full Web Bot 0516B|Full Web Bot 2816B|8484 Boston Project v 1\.0|Atomic_Email_Hunter/4\.0|atSpider/1\.0|autoemailspider|bwh3_user_agent|China Local Browse 2\.6|ContactBot/0\.2|ContentSmartz|DataCha0s/2\.0|DBrowse 1\.4b|DBrowse 1\.4d|Demo Bot DOT 16b|Demo Bot Z 16b|DSurf15a 01|DSurf15a 71|DSurf15a 81|DSurf15a VA|EBrowse 1\.4b|Educate Search VxB|EmailSiphon|EmailSpider|EmailWolf 1\.00|ESurf15a 15|ExtractorPro|Franklin Locator 1\.8|FSurf15a 01|Full Web Bot 0416B|Full Web Bot 0516B|Full Web Bot 2816B|8484 Boston Project v 1\.0|Atomic_Email_Hunter/4\.0|atSpider/1\.0|autoemailspider|bwh3_user_agent|China Local Browse 2\.6|ContactBot/0\.2|ContentSmartz|DataCha0s/2\.0|DBrowse 1\.4b|DBrowse 1\.4d|Demo Bot DOT 16b|Demo Bot Z 16b|DSurf15a 01|DSurf15a 71|DSurf15a 81|DSurf15a VA|EBrowse 1\.4b|Educate Search VxB|EmailSiphon|EmailSpider|EmailWolf 1\.00|ESurf15a 15|ExtractorPro|Franklin Locator 1\.8|FSurf15a 01|Full Web Bot 0416B|Full Web Bot 0516B|Full Web Bot 2816B

failregex = ^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST).*HTTP.*"(?:%(badbots)s|%(badbotscustom)s)"$

ignoreregex =

# DEV Notes:
# List of bad bots fetched from http://www.user-agents.org
# Generated on Sat Feb  9 12:59:57 EST 2019 by ./files/gen_badbots.
#
# Author: Yaroslav Halchenko
```

Comment: It seems to work with the modification on failregex, thanks